# XQuery wont return a document

Tags: sql, t-sql, xquery

I just started learning about XQuery and am trying to play with it a little.
Now, iv'e built what i think is a simple query and a correct one (a much as i can see) but SQL Manger
prints me the error: 
XQuery [query()]: "=" was expected.
I looked back at the code but i cant understand how to fix it..
here is my code:

```
DECLARE @x AS XML = N'
<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="children">
<title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
<author>J K. Rowling</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web">
<title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
<author>James McGovern</author>
<author>Per Bothner</author>
<author>Kurt Cagle</author>
<author>James Linn</author>
<author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>49.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web" cover="paperback">
<title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
<author>Erik T. Ray</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>39.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>';

SELECT @x.query('for $i in bookstore/book
    let $a := $i/author
    let $t := $i/title
    let $p := $i/price
    where $i/@price < 40
    return
    <This is a test>
    <author>$a</author>
    <title>$t</title>
    <price>$p</price>
    </This is a test>')
AS [I hope this works]
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid xml element:

```
<This is a test>
```

changing this to

```
<ThisIsATest>
```

will fix your query but after the fix, as-is, your query doesn't return anything. My T-SQL XQuery skills are rusty but you can get what you're trying to do using `nodes` and the `values` method.

**This:**

```
SELECT 
  author = bs.book.value('(author/text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)'),
  title  = bs.book.value('(title/text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)'),
  price  = bs.book.value('(price/text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)')
FROM        (VALUES(@x))                 AS ml(x)
CROSS APPLY ml.x.nodes('bookstore/book') AS bs(book);
```

**Returns:**

```
author                title                 price
--------------------- --------------------- ----------
Giada De Laurentiis   Everyday Italian      30.00
J K. Rowling          Harry Potter          29.99
James McGovern        XQuery Kick Start     49.99
Erik T. Ray           Learning XML          39.95
```

**This** (which includes your sample XML):

```
DECLARE @x AS XML = N'
<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="children">
<title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
<author>J K. Rowling</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web">
<title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
<author>James McGovern</author>
<author>Per Bothner</author>
<author>Kurt Cagle</author>
<author>James Linn</author>
<author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>49.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web" cover="paperback">
<title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
<author>Erik T. Ray</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>39.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>';

SELECT 
  author = bs.book.value('(author/text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)'),
  title  = bs.book.value('(title/text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)'),
  price  = bs.book.value('(price/text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)')
FROM        (VALUES(@x))                 AS ml(x)
CROSS APPLY ml.x.nodes('bookstore/book') AS bs(book)
FOR XML PATH('Book');
```

**Returns:**

```
<Book>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <title>Everyday Italian</title>
  <price>30.00</price>
</Book>
<Book>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <title>Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</Book>
<Book>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <title>XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <price>49.99</price>
</Book>
<Book>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <title>Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</Book>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but there are three things to mention:

1. As Alan Burstein has told you, the tag `<This is a test>` is not valid. The message you get, is because the engine thinks of an element `<This>` and expects the `is` to be the first attribute, which should be followed by `=` like in `<This is="some value">`.
2. Your `where` tries to query a `@price` attribute
3. In order to resolve the values you need `{}` around your variables.

Try this:

```
SELECT @x.query('for $i in bookstore/book
    let $a := $i/author
    let $t := $i/title
    let $p := $i/price
    where $p < 40
    return
    <This-is-a-test>
    <author>{$a}</author>
    <title>{$t}</title>
    <price>{$p}</price>
    </This-is-a-test>')
AS [I hope this works]
```